# Javascript Function get elements contents

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I was using a listener to trigger a certain code:

```
$(".item-actions > .like-button").click(function (e) {
    oid = $(this).parent().attr('data-oid');
    alert(oid);
    });
```

Now instead of a listener I'm simply calling the function on the HTML.

CLICK

I'm having problems getting the element's content, and parent content as I'm not able to use $(this) to select them. How can I do the same I was doing with the function?

I first tried this which didn't work:

```
function alertOID() {
  oid = $(this).parent().attr('data-oid');
  alert(oid);
}
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

on **.like-button** html onclick event call **alertOID()** like this **alertOID(this)**

```
<input class="like-button" onClick="alertOID.call(this);">
```

instead of

```
<input class="like-button" onClick="alertOID.call();">
```

and change alertOID like this

```
function alertOID(element) {
    oid = $(element).parent().attr('data-oid');
    alert(oid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
<input class="like-button" onClick="alertOID.call(this);">
```